# Grails application - redirect non-www version to www version of the website

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, redirect

Our Grails application is deployed on VPS but the www and non-www versions are
not the same. There are actually two sites, that is there are two cookies in the browser, one for each version, so the user logged in in non-www version is not logged in in www version.

What is the best way to point non-www version to www version in Grails? We are
using Tomcat as the application server.

I was thinking to create a Grails filter and change all non-www urls to the same url with www appended and to do a permanent redirect. But I am not sure if this is a good way to do it. We don't have Apache server in front of Tomcat so we can't use it's url rewriting mechanism.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have access to the main Tomcat configuration?  Tomcat can do virtual hosting, so you could set up a separate virtual host with a simple webapp to do the redirecting.

**conf/server.xml**

```xml
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" ...>
    <!-- current configuration, this Host will serve www.example.com -->
  </Host>

  <Host name="example.com" appBase="nonwww-webapps" />
</Engine>
```

**nonwww-webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>redirectToWww</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/redirect.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>redirectToWww</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**nonwww-webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/redirect.jsp**

```
<% response.sendRedirect("http://www.example.com" + request.getRequestURI() +
      (request.getQueryString() == null
          ? ""
          : ("?" + request.getQueryString())
      )); %>
```

Or alternatively, if you want a 301 instead of 302 redirect

```
<% response.setStatus(301);
   response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.example.com" + request.getRequestURI() +
      (request.getQueryString() == null
          ? ""
          : ("?" + request.getQueryString())
      ));
   response.setHeader("Connection", "close"); %>
```

Comment: +1 because this solution saved my day. BUT my SEO engineer looks very sad because the browser says it's a 302, not 301 - could you explain if 301 would be possible instead of 302 with this solution?

Comment: did it - the jsp code now looks like this 
`<%
 response.setStatus(301);
 response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.example.com" + request.getRequestURI() +
   (request.getQueryString() == null ? "" : ("?" + request.getQueryString())));
 response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
%>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an Apache server in front of your Tomcat you could use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/#download). A tool to perform URL rewrite like Apache but directly with Tomcat (and other web application server).